# Center alignment with multirow package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multirow

I have a multirow environment, but it does not center aligned in center environment. What might be wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
         {\bf Group} & {\bf Name} & {\bf Parameters} \\
         \midrule\midrule[.1em]

     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack} 
        & {\tt push}
        & {\tt store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt pop}
        & {\tt success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt load}
        & {\tt success} \\    
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt save}
        & {\tt success} \\   
    \midrule[.1em] 

     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack} 
        & {\tt push}
        & {\tt store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt pop}
        & {\tt success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt load}
        & {\tt success} \\    
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt save}
        & {\tt success} \\   

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `\multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack}` to `\multirow{5}{2.5cm}{Stack}`. (The three `\cmidrule` instructions add extra (vertical) whitespace, amounting to about 1 extra "real" row.) By the way, using `\midrule\midrule[.1em]` seems overkill. A single `\midrule` should do just fine.

Comment: Never put table into `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}. Instead this rather write \begin{table[htb]\centering ... \end{table}`

Comment: The simplest solution is, of course, not using `\multirow` and letting “Stack” stay where it belong, that is, at the top of the otherwise empty space. Besides, you should know that `\bf` and `\tt` have been deprecated more than twenty years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Change `\multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack}` to `\multirow{5}{2.5cm}{Stack}`
- Replace all `\cmidrule` directives with `\addlinespace`
- Use a single `\midrule` after the header row
- Use a common line width (say, `0.1em`) for all `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` statements.
- Provide more structure in the setup of the tabular environment, so that you don't have to type all those `\tt` directives in the body of the table.
- Don't encase the `table` environment in a `center` environment. Instead, use a single `\centering` statement after `\begin{table}`.
- Optional: Don't use **bold** for the words in the header row: They already stand out sufficiently by virtue of their placement at the top of the table. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array,caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{2.5cm} *{2}{>{\ttfamily}l} @{}}
    \toprule[.1em]
    Group & \normalfont Name & \normalfont Parameters \\
    \midrule[.1em]
      \multirow{5}{*}{Stack} & push & store \\
      \addlinespace 
      & pop & success \\
      \addlinespace 
      & load& success \\    
      \addlinespace 
      & save& success \\   
    \midrule[.1em] 
      \multirow{5}{*}{Stack} 
      & push & store \\
      \addlinespace
      & pop  & success \\
      \addlinespace
      & load & success \\    
      \addlinespace
      & save & success \\   
    \bottomrule[.1em]
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about if you added another line, say under the first *load*-line. Using `\multirow{6}{*}{Stack}` looks definitely wrong, same width `\multirow{5}{*}{Stack}`. I think you would need to use the `fixup`-parameter here.

Comment: @runartrollet - Honestly, my preferred approach would be to get rid of the extra spacing between the short rows. That way -- purely as a (happy) side-effect --`\multirow` could be used without further ado. Even better (as egreg has hinted as well, see above), don't use \multirow to begin with. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For vertical positioning obey Mico comment, but you use in table commands from TeX not LaTeX, better and simpler code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
\begin{tabular}{p{25mm} >{\ttfamily}l >{\ttfamily}l}
    \toprule
\thead{Group} & \thead{Name} & \thead{Parameters} \\
         \midrule\midrule[.1em]

     \multirow{5}*{Stack}
        & push
        & store \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & pop
        & success \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & load
        & success \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & save
        & success \\
    \midrule[.1em]

     \multirow{5}*{Stack}
        & push
        & store \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & pop
        & success \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & load
        & success \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & save
        & success \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I add package `makecell` for formating column heads with macro `\thead{...}`. Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the `multirow`-documentation:

> It’s just about impossible to deal correctly with descenders. The text will be set up centred, but it may then have a baseline that doesn’t match the baseline of the stuff beside it, in particular if the stuff beside it has descenders and text does not. This may result in a small misalignment. About all that can be done is to do a final touchup on text, using the fixup optional argument. (Hint: If you use a measure like .1ex, there’s a reasonable chance that the fixup will still be correct if you change the point size.)

So we need to use the fixup-parameter.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
         {\bf Group} & {\bf Name} & {\bf Parameters} \\
         \midrule\midrule[.1em]

     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}[-1.5ex]{ Stack} 
        & {\tt push}
        & {\tt store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt pop}
        & {\tt success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt load}
        & {\tt success} \\    
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt save}
        & {\tt success} \\   
    \midrule[.1em] 

     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}[-1.5ex]{Stack} 
        & {\tt push}
        & {\tt store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt pop}
        & {\tt success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt load}
        & {\tt success} \\    
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & {\tt save}
        & {\tt success} \\   

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Some Suggestions

The look of the table could be improved a bit. Don't use `\begin{centering}`, it adds some unnecessary vertical space. Also, we probably don't need all of the rules. Especially double rules. To seperate some rows, which might otherwise be difficult to distinguish, it could be better to simply add some space with `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`-package. Also, as others have pointed out, use `array`-package so you don't need to write the same thing so many times. For the header you can add a command which sets the header-format.

Also, is seems, that as I have made the changes with removing the rules and inserting the space, there is no longer any use of the fixup-parameter as it has centered nicely, so I just removed it.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\headerFormat}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}lll}
    \toprule
         \headerFormat Group & \headerFormat Name & \headerFormat Parameters \\
         \midrule
     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack} 
        & push
        & store \\
        & pop
        & success \\
        & load
        & success \\    
        & save
        & success \\   
   \addlinespace
     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}{Stack} 
        & push
        & store \\
        & pop
        & success \\
        & load
        & success \\    
        & save
        & success \\   
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `\multirow` identifiers into position using a precise `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l >{\ttfamily}l >{\ttfamily}l }
  \toprule
  \bfseries Group & \rmfamily\bfseries Name & \rmfamily\bfseries Parameters \\
  \midrule\midrule[.1em]
    & push
    & store \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\normalbaselineskip-.5\cmidrulewidth-.5\aboverulesep}[0pt][0pt]{Stack}
    & pop
    & success \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & load
    & success \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & save
    & success \\
  \midrule[.1em]
    & push
    & store \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\normalbaselineskip-.5\cmidrulewidth-.5\aboverulesep}[0pt][0pt]{Stack}
    & pop
    & success \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & load
    & success \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & save
    & success \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've also simplified your input using `\bfseries` and some [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) insertions via `>{\ttfamily}` before each of the last two columns.

Answer (score 1):

*Some improvements:*

Load `caption` to have a decent spacing between caption and tabular (LaTeX doesn't swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` when caption is above the float). Don't use a `center` environment with floats, as it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead, *inside* the table environment. Don't use `\bf`, `\tt`, &c., but `\bfseries` or `\textbf`, `\ttfamily` or `\texttt`. I added a small correction to `\multirow` for vertical centring of the contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption} \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \caption{Virtual Machine Byte Code}\label{tab:vm}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
         \textbf{Group} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Parameters} \\
         \midrule\midrule[.1em]
     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}[-1.5ex]{\centering Stack}
        & \texttt{push}
        & \texttt{store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{pop}
        & \texttt{success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{load}
        & \texttt{success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{save}
        & \texttt{success} \\
    \midrule[.1em]
     \multirow{4}{2.5cm}[-1.5ex]{\centering Stack}
        & \texttt{push}
        & \texttt{store} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{pop}
        & \texttt{success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{load}
        & \texttt{success} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        & \texttt{save}
        & \texttt{success} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]